# Popen error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'minisat': 'minisat'

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, sat, sat-solvers

I am trying to run a SAT solver on a bunch of cnf encodings that my program has generated. I have installed minisat on my laptop (MacOS) via homebrew and I can just run minisat on the terminal as:

`$ minisat INPUT_FILE.cnf OUTPUT_FILE.txt`

But because I have hundreds of encoding I wrote a custom command using `subprocess`. The encoding is genrated inside a `for` loop. The loop also contains the subprocess command and ideally the SAT solver (minisat) runs on each file every loop.

The cnf encoding is generated fine and I can run them individually on the terminal but when I try to run the use the subprocess command it throws an error saying:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'minisat': 'minisat'`

Here is my code (it is just a part of my code and I have left out the irrelevant parts):

```py
solver = 'minisat'

for i in range...:

    encoding = generate_encoding()

    cnf = 'generated_cnf_encoding'+ str(i) +'.cnf'

    #write encoding to cnf
    ...

    sol = 'empty_output_file'+ str(i) +'.txt'

    cmd = [solver, cnf, sol]

    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    output, err = p.communicate()

    print(err)
```

EDIT: On several other solutions mentioned here, it was suggested to add `shell=True` but that throws the `minisat: command not found` when printing `err`

Answer (score 0):

Please run following code to see if it runs the **minisat** command at least once. And paste the output here.

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['minisat', INPUT_FILE.cnf OUTPUT_FILE.txt], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: I get the same error as before which is `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'minisat': 'minisat'`

Comment: It means that system Python subprocess cannot find minisat. Make sure it is in path. export `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH` then `source ~/.bash_profile` Or check folder in which minisat is installed.

Comment: If the issue persist then try `import os` and  `os.path.expandvars("$PATH")`